# trackpad configuration settings

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, configuration, trackpad

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a System76 Galago UltrPro. I have not been able to configure the trackpad and get the settings to stick. I am trying to change the sensitivity and palm detection, those settings are not in the system settings mouse page. However, I can configure it pretty well via xinput in a terminal, but the changes are lost whenever I restart.

Is there some way to make these settings through the GUI? If not which files does the configuration setting go into?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the System76 Driver installed, along with all of the latest updates installed.

To install the System76 Driver, open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then enter all of the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76-dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install system76-driver
```

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11692/253579 << Hey Ian; Would you care to chime in whether you think a system76 tag would be useful for you? This could allow you to be notified of system76 tagged messages.

Comment: Ian, thanks for the response. The newest driver is already installed, according to apt-get. I keep all my computers up to date. I am wondering which config file I should put the settings changes into, so they are applied with each restart? There must be a way to do this, but it is not obvious to me.